# A standard Missouri state license plate consists of a sequence of two letters, one digit, one letter, and one digit.

Tags: combinatorics

A standard Missouri state license plate consists of a sequence of two letters, one digit, one letter, and one digit. How many such license plates can be made?

Comment: Start small. How many sequences of $2$ not necessarily distinct letters are there?

Answer (score 1):

L-L-D-L-D:

- L = letter $\in \{a, b, c, d, ..., x, y, z\}$; $\;26$ letters in the alphabet
- D = Digit $\in \{0, 1, 2, ..., 8, 9\}$; $\;10$ possible digits to choose from

You have:

$\quad$ ___options for the first letter

$\times $ ___options for the second letter (not necessarily distinct from the first letter)

$\times$ ___options for the first digit

$\times$ ___options for the last letter, (not necessarily distinct from the first or second letter)

$\times$ ___options for the last digit...(not necessarily distinct from the first digit)

= total number of possible license plates that can be produced in Missouri.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Total number of arrangements = the product of the number of arrangements at each position.

Answer (score 0):

$L$ is a letter in $\{a,b,c,d,\dotsc,x,y,z\}$; $26$ letters in the alphabet.

$D$ is a Digit in $\{0,1,2,\dotsc,8,9\}$; $10$ possible digits to choose from

$$26\cdot26\cdot10\cdot26\cdot10 = 1757600$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).